# How do I render CSS Borders in Gmail?

Tags: html, css, gmail, rendering, html-email

I am trying to send an HTML email through a G Suite account. When I open my HTML in my web browser, it renders perfectly:
[image]

However, when send the HTML in an email, the border does not render:
[image]

I tried using inline styles, and I tried wrapping everything in the body in a separate `div`. Nothing worked. This is the HTML I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>[spelab] EoD.md</title>
    <style>
        /* CSS in concern */
            body {
               border: 2px solid red;
               border-radius: 5px;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body id="preview">
    <h4 class="code-line" data-line-end="1" data-line-start="0"><a id="Things_I_Did_Today_0"></a>Things I Did Today</h4>
    <hr>
    <ul>
        <li class="has-line-data" data-line-end="3" data-line-start="2"><strong>Mail/messages.</strong></li>
        <li class="has-line-data" data-line-end="3" data-line-start="2"><strong>Finished testing product 1234.</strong></li>
        <li class="has-line-data" data-line-end="3" data-line-start="2"><strong>Finished report on product 5678.</strong></li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    <p class="has-line-data" data-line-end="11" data-line-start="4">John Doe<br> Senior example position<br> Example Company<br> 1234 Main Street Washington, NY 12345<br>
        <a href="">email@example.com</a><br>
        <a href="">Website@example.com</a><br>
        <a href="tel:+1-123-455-7891">+1 (123) 456-7891</a>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is Gmail not rendering the border? Is there a workaround? Is it perhaps related to the way I am [transferring the HTML to my email](https://htmlemail.io/blog/how-to-send-html-emails-in-gmail)?

Comment: `border` is supported. try to check generated HTML/CSS code, maybe try to use inlien styles... https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/reference/supported_css

Comment: @pavel I have actually already tried using inline styles. I will clarify that in my question

Comment: Try wrapping the entire body in a div and add a border to the div.

Comment: @SinestroWhite that doesn't seem to work. Also, Google Chrome keeps forcing the div to be a child of `body`, even when I edit the HTML in notepad.

Comment: I meant the other way around the div in the body, sorry for misleading you.

Comment: @SinestroWhite no worries. However, I have also tried that. No luck

Answer (score 3):

Most webmails don't support styles selectors targeting the `body` element. And rightly so! In a webmail like Gmail’s desktop webmail, your HTML is actually included in the webmail’s own HTML. If they let you style the `body`, that means you could actually change Gmail’s own interface! So you can’t do that in Gmail.

However, something peculiar that happens in Gmail’s desktop webmail in particular is that the `<body>` element in your HTML email is turned into a `<div>`, with some of your attributes applied onto it. So if you had your styles inlined in the `<body>` in your example (`<body id="preview" style="border: 2px solid red; border-radius: 5px;">`), Gmail would turn it into:

```html
<div id="m_1234123412344123434preview" style="border: 2px solid red; border-radius: 5px;">
```

So this could work in your case, but that definitely wouldn't work in other webmails that don't have the same behavior (like Yahoo’s desktop webmail for example). So my recommendation would be, as [suggested by another user in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65258016/how-do-i-render-css-borders-in-gmail#comment115370591_65258016), to add a wrapping `<div>` inside the `body` of your email. Like the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>[spelab] EoD.md</title>
</head>
<body id="preview">
    <div style="border: 2px solid red; border-radius: 5px;">
        <h4 class="code-line" data-line-end="1" data-line-start="0"><a id="Things_I_Did_Today_0"></a>Things I Did Today</h4>
        <hr>
        <ul>
            <li class="has-line-data" data-line-end="3" data-line-start="2"><strong>Mail/messages.</strong></li>
            <li class="has-line-data" data-line-end="3" data-line-start="2"><strong>Finished testing product 1234.</strong></li>
            <li class="has-line-data" data-line-end="3" data-line-start="2"><strong>Finished report on product 5678.</strong></li>
        </ul>
        <hr>
        <p class="has-line-data" data-line-end="11" data-line-start="4">John Doe<br> Senior example position<br> Example Company<br> 1234 Main Street Washington, NY 12345<br>
            <a href="">email@example.com</a><br>
            <a href="">Website@example.com</a><br>
            <a href="tel:+1-123-455-7891">+1 (123) 456-7891</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This answer seems very well informed, and I was really hoping it would work. Unfortunately, it does not. Also, if you read the comments on my question, you will that I have already tried this.

Comment: I'm sorry this didn't work for you. Here's [a test on Email on Acid](https://app.emailonacid.com/app/acidtest/1Wrp4nes2NJ8hBXWPrADw3xcokml3Y5GXtDMyU3aYetpw/list) from the code I posted above. I would guess your problem comes from something else than the HTML. Could you give more details about how exactly you're sending your email?

Comment: Look at the end of my question. I explained there how I'm sending my email.

Comment: While this is definitely not a recommended method to send HTML emails (because all your code will be filtered by the email client you're sending from), I just tried to copy and paste my above code in a new Gmail compose window and it just works.

Comment: i see... so this is the webemail problems ... that's why most of the email template are using images as a trick...